# Parsing a file that looks like a list into a list

Tags: python, list

I have a file, that looks like a list it's one long string of words in quotes, separated by commas. So when I read from the file, I get something like:

```
'"abc","def","ghi","jkl"\n'
```

I want to parse this file into a list of strings. Here's my implementation of that parsing:

```
words = f.readline()
words = names.rstrip('\n')
words = [x.strip('"') for x in words.split(',')]
```

my list would then be:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
```

This is only 3 lines of code, but it looks remarkably like the original file input. I can't help thinking that I can do better. The file already looks like it's in the form of a list, except it's a string. Is there any way that Python can simply turn it into a list without deconstructing what already looks like a list of strings and remaking it?

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is the stringified version (the `repr`) of a python literal (without the brackets it's a `tuple` instead of a `list`, but that's not terribly important).

You can use `ast.literal_eval` to safely turn it back into a python object:

```
s = '"abc","def","ghi","jkl"\n'

from ast import literal_eval

literal_eval(s)
Out[155]: ('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl')
```

it even handles the newline character for you.